# PHP 7: SessionHandlerInterface::read(string $session_id): string must be compatible with SessionHandlerInterface::read($key)

Tags: php, session, php-7.1

with the following code under PHP 7.1

```
class MySqlSessionHandler implements \SessionHandlerInterface   {
     public function read(string $session_id) : string  { ... }
}
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Declaration of Sessions\MySqlSessionHandler::read(string
>   $session_id): string must be compatible with
>   SessionHandlerInterface::read($key)

When I remove the type declaration "string" instead like

```
public function read($session_id) : string  { ... }
```

no exception is thrown. The same is happening with all other SessionHandlerInterface functions. Reading PHP documentation type string should be correct.

What is wrong ?

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate of the linked question. That question has a mismatch between a user-defined interface and a class, while this problem is caused by a [bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72285). The documented method signature in the official manual is wrong; at this time, type declarations cannot be used when implementing the `SessionHanderInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

Original signature of the function does not containg typing, therefore when you add your "string" then it's different signature, so you either add "string" to interface signature or remove from implementation

Comment: I see - thanks for the quick answer. I will remove from my implementation